# Why do Ubuntu LTS releases provide 5 years of support? What happens during the lifecycle of an LTS release on a production server to need 5 years?

Tags: server, support

Also, what do IT teams of production servers do to prepare for end of support and transition from an older LTS release to a newer one?

Comment: The questions you asked in the title are easy. Where's the practicality in constantly changing operating system versions if you need a stable release? The 5 years of support are necessary in order to recitfy any security issues or other bugs, and no potentially system-breaking changes are introduced. It also gives the server managers plenty of time to prepare for the next release, and anticipate any major kernel changes, etc. It's just common sense really

Comment: For many companies, 5 years isn't long enough, which Ubuntu caters for as the five years you mention refers to *standard* support, which can be extended using ESM. Your question though is vague & varies on industry/purpose of the machine, let alone organizations.vary in skills etc... and any answer will be opinion (off-topic on this site) & specific to certain organizations/jurisdictions that may differ to others.

Comment: We start planning for the upgrade at the beginning of the 5 years (and we don't wait until the End-Of-Life, just until the next LTS is a available) . We identify our own critical programs and services and the shared libraries and the build tools and the connections and ... whatever is "critical". Prepare a test environment, set up automatic testing. Install early versions of the next LTS, test, resolve problems,, lather, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Each LTS that Canonical (a for-profit company which is NOT AskUbuntu) or AskUbuntu supports requires a certain set of resources (the people familiar with old releases, the hardware to run it on, ...).

As you look at older and older releases, you'll find that they differ more and more from the current release in that they support a smaller variety of hardware and software, and they do some system management tasks differently. This makes "support" more difficult.

That Canonical supports LTS releases for 5 years, and releases new LTS releases every 2 years is their business decision.

What this means is that, 2 years into your 5 year window, a new LTS release is available for testing, and eventual migration. You have 3 years for testing.